# How to create a dictionary of list in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a table as follows which I'm getting from a mysql database:

```
Col2   | Col3                   | Col4
1      | Name1(something_1234)  | Some_date
1      | Name1(something_3456)  | Some_date
2      | Name3(something_7890)  | Some_date
2      | Name4(something_0988)  | Some_date
```

And I'm getting this data into html using javascript as follows:

```
<script>
            var new_col2 = [], new_col3 =[];
            {% for b in obj %}
            new_col2.push("{{b.col2 }}");
            new_col3.push("{{b.col3 }}");
            {% endfor %}
            console.log(new_col2);
            console.log(new_col3);
    </script>
```

Is it possible to create a dictionary as follows using javascript using the above for loop:

```
{'1': ['Name1(something_1234)', 'Name1(something_3456)'], '2': 'Name3(something_7890)', 'Name4(something_0988)']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
            var dictionary = {}
            {% for b in obj %}
                if (!dictionary["{{b.col2 }}"]) {
                    dictionary["{{b.col2 }}"] = [];
                }
                dictionary["{{b.col2 }}"].push({{b.col3 }});
            {% endfor %}
            console.log(dictionary);            
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that obj is **javascript** list of object 
we can loop through the list, and push each row into the map we will create, 
if you don't know map, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

something like this.

```
var myMap= new Map();
obj.forEach(function(element) {
   // my map set (key , value )
    myMap.set(element.col2,element.col3);
});
```

you can access the value of key 1 `myMap.get(1);`, this will return the value mapped with key 1.